# Italy is to Hungary as Netherlands is to France

Tags: pattern, geography, knowledge

This puzzle talks about a certain (clear and justifiable) relationship between certain independent countries. With respect to this relation, we have

> Italy : Hungary = Netherlands : France = Austria : ?????

and

> Cote D'Ivoire : Ireland = Iran : Tajikistan = ????? : Uzbekistan

and

> Mali : ????? = Indonesia : Poland

**What is this relation?**
**What are the hidden countries?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### 1) Canada or Peru (the flag colours are the same, but rotated)

(If you also want to keep the dimensions of the stripes, then only Peru is accepted.)

[image: Austria]
[image: Peru]

#### 2) Sierra Leone (same colours, horizontally symmetrical)

[image: Uzbekistan]
[image: Sierra Leone]

#### 3) Guinea (same colours, vertically symmetrical)

[image: Mali]
[image: Guinea]

Comment: Anyone who reads Polandball should find this easy :P

Comment: @MarchHo: exactly, Indonesia : Poland and the venerable bastion of knowledge called Polandball provided the clue to me :-)

Comment: @MarchHo what is a Polandball?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polandball 
It's basically a meme where countries are represented as spheres with the colours of their flag.

Comment: The game. @MarchHo

Answer (score 4):

> Austria peru flag 90 degree pattern
>
>  Sierra Leone with upside down pattern
>
>  Guinea mirrors